# Docker swarm: REST API accessible on port 3001, but not accessible through web-server

Tags: rest, api, curl, docker, docker-swarm

I have the following setup:

network: ingress (Swarm)
Service:
   web
   api

The web service is running in a container with port 3000 exposed, and api is running in a container with port 3001 exposed.

I can query localhost:3000 or IP-address:3000 (from any other machine), and the webapp loads. Moreover, I can POST to the api at localhost:3001 or IP-address:3001 (from any other machine) and I will get the desired response.

Within the web-app, there is a REST-endpoint which allows me to POST data to port 3000 at /api endpoint, which redirects that POST request to 3001 on the api container.

The problem is that when I post data to the 3000:/api, curl just hangs. No response, no nothing, and I don't know what to do.

From the documentation, it says that all containers on the same network can access each other's ports regardless of whether or not they are published/exposed.

I'm confused why it's not working. Plus, I dont even get an error, curl just doesn't return a value at all.

Example:

```
docker swarm init
docker service create --name=web --mode global --publish 3000:3000 project/web
docker service create --name=api --replicas 5 --publish 3001:3001 project/api
```

Now, if I run the following command from another computer on the network, it works fine:

```
curl <IP_address>:3000
```

Returns index.html from the web-app
    curl :3001/predict --data '{...}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
Returns the correct data as needed

Now, the web-app has an endpoint :3000/api/predict, which takes the json from the body, and then posts the same data to localhost:3001/predict endpoint (which is on the other container).

If I ssh into the container, the curl request returns an error for Connection refused.

I also tried to replace the "localhost" with the name of one of the replicated containers, or the name of the service.

I always get curl: (6) Could not resolve host: marine

Comment: Post the code which handles the post and do you post it to 127.0.0.1:3001 or service name 3001? Also post requests cannot be redirected or rewritten as that makes it a get operation and the data is lost during redirect.

Comment: I can't post the code sadly, but it seems like the problem is with the hostname. If I ssh into the running webapp container, I can't POST the data via curl to the other container. Is there a best practice to establish communication between containers on the same network.

Comment: Explain the flow with example urls so we can understand better and comment

Comment: Hi Tarun, updated just now

Comment: Ok, so I was able to resolve some of the issue. I can now ssh into the container and successfully POST to the endpoint, but I cannot do so from outside the container.

Comment: Can you add the output of `curl -vL IP:3000/api/predict` to your question.